# Darken the image and place a half triangle on hover

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

For example: In the picture shown below, how can I get that cut edge (with the arrow pointing towards it) and darkened view when someone places a mouse cursor over the image.

[image]

I am really new to programming and still learning. I would really appreciate it if you could write sample code to get that type of view.

Your help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Only the part of the image where the arrow is and not the rest of the image? Hm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a pseudo element method, but to begin with and not to confuse, I have used an additional element which will be the arrow. *Code explanation in comments*

To understand how the arrow was created, you need to see this demo first: [**How CSS triangles work**](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh)

```css
.image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image img {
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
.image:hover img { /* Darkening effect on mouseover */
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.image .arrow { /* Creates a half triangle with top and left arrow transparent */
  opacity: 0;
  border-color: transparent #f2f2f2 #f2f2f2 transparent;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  position: relative;
}
.image:hover .arrow { /* Mouseover effect */
  opacity: 1;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 0;
}


.image:hover .arrow {
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 45px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 0;
}
.image .arrow {
    border-color: transparent #f2f2f2 #f2f2f2 transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.image .arrow span {
    left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/sports" />
  <div class="arrow"><span>></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ignore the above comment, it looks like unicode only has a filled arrow and nothing resembling a greater than symbol - http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar do i need to place these code (inside the 2 box), one below the other..if yes..well..it's not working for me..anyways..thanks for answering!!!

Comment: I guess you are very new to HTML/CSS, You need to place the CSS inside `<style></style>`. @Harry Any unicode suggestions for a narrower arrow?

Comment: @ManojKumar: Nope, I thought there was one but it seems to be a filled arrow (2nd row, 1st symbol in the link I provided in previous comment). By the way that comment would have pinged only me and not OP. Edit the `@` now that I've already seen it :)

Comment: Thanks @ManojKumar it worked perfectly..is it possible to get the (>) sign exactly... Between(at the centre) of the triangle.

Comment: @harsher Yes, you can. Wrap the text inside span and use position values.

Comment: Thankyou@Manojkumar..is it possible to write a text on that shadowed image...i mean when the shadow comes on the image..is it possible to display a text on it(shadow).

Comment: I guess you need to post a new question for that.